# Serverless error EMFILE too many open files

Tags: node.js, jenkins, serverless

I currently have been having issues with building and deploying a serverless app.

I am getting error too many open files like the below. I have tried a few things like upgrading Node but this is still an issue.

My Jenkins runs as a container service in ECS.

````
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies... 
  Error --------------------------------------------------

  Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/basten_master/.gradle/nodejs/node-v14.21.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/uri-js/dist/esnext/index.d.ts'```
````